# Nesting transaction scopes for integration tests using Rhino Commons UnitOfWork

Tags: nhibernate, transactionscope, unit-of-work, rhino-commons

I'm trying to set up a integration test class that wraps each test in a transaction.  This way I can rollback the transaction after each test instead of resetting the DB before each test.

I also want to be able to use transactions in the integration tests themselves.

I am using NHibernate and the Rhino Commons UnitOfWork for the the project.  I am using MSTest for the tests.

I want something like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit() {
    // create outer transaction scope
    UnitOfWork.Start();
    UnitOfWork.Current.BeginTransaction();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup() {
    // rollback outer transaction
    UnitOfWork.Current.Dispose();
}

[TestMethod]
public void IntegrationTest() {
    using (UnitOfWork.Start(UnitOfWorkNestingOptions.CreateNewOrNestUnitOfWork)) {
        UnitOfWork.Current.BeginTransaction();

        // integration test code

        UnitOfWork.Current.TransactionalFlush();

        // possibly more transactions
    }
}
```

This is the first time I have used NHibernate, Rhino Commons, and MSTest.  I am not clear on the behavior of sessions with nested Rhino Commons `UnitOfWork`s.  What I have here does not rollback the changes from the integration test.

I tried using `TransactionScope` from `System.Transactions`, but get the following error when the `UnitOfWork`s end:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Disconnect cannot be called while a transaction is in progress..

So here are my questions:
Is there a way to get this behavior with UnitOfWork in Rhino Commons?  If not, should I just reset the database before each test or is there another way to nest transactions that plays nicely with the UnitOfWork?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `UnitOfWork.Start().BeginTransaction()` returns a `RhinoTransaction`. So to make it more clear you can try to rewrite the code as this:

```
using(IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Start(UnitOfWorkNestingOptions.CreateNewOrNestUnitOfWork))
{
    RhinoTransaction tx = uow.BeginTransaction();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    tx.Rollback();
}
```

Be warned though, I have not tried the code above, let me know if it works.